# Why a custom exception must have default parameter when raised in ProcessPoolExecutor?

Tags: python, multithreading, exception

I have a ProcessPoolExecutor and want to raise a custom exception in it. But it only works without breaking the process pool when it has a default parameter or used in super init or just go around that super init function.
I have no clue about this behaviour.
On Py3.7 and 3.8 this is shown:
`A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending.`
Any Ideas?

```py
from concurrent.futures.process import ProcessPoolExecutor


class PoolBreaker(Exception):
    def __init__(self, num):
        super().__init__()
        self.num = num


class NoPoolBreaker(Exception):
    def __init__(self, num=0):
        super().__init__()
        self.num = num


class NoPoolBreaker2(Exception):
    def __init__(self, num):
        super().__init__(num)
        self.num = num


class NoPoolBreaker3(Exception):
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.num = num


def get_result(job):
    exc = job.exception()
    if type(exc) is PoolBreaker:
        print("PoolBreaker", exc.num)
    elif type(exc) is NoPoolBreaker:
        print("NoPoolBreaker", exc.num)
    elif type(exc) is NoPoolBreaker2:
        print("NoPoolBreaker2", exc.num)
    elif type(exc) is NoPoolBreaker3:
        print("NoPoolBreaker3", exc.num)
    else:
        print(f"Exception: {str(exc)}")


def work(x: int):
    if x == 0:
        raise PoolBreaker(x)
    elif x == 1:
        raise NoPoolBreaker(x)
    elif x == 2:
        raise NoPoolBreaker2(x)
    elif x == 3:
        raise NoPoolBreaker3(x)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for num in range(0, 4):
        with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
            job = executor.submit(work, num)
        get_result(job)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was/is a bug in the python pickle, more details can be found here: https://bugs.python.org/issue37208

Answer (score 0):

I also came over the problem, and I am very confused about it. This only happens with ProcessPoolExecutor, not with ThreadPoolExecutor.

The problem is that ProcessPoolExecutor tries to create a copy of the Exception through creating a second time. To do so, ProcessPoolExecutor seems to inspect the ‘upper’ class – e.g. Exception except in NoPoolBreaker3, where the upper class is NoPoolBreaker3 itself – for its attributes. Since Exception does not always hold all attributes of the whole object, it fails.

You will see that if you add a print into the constructor:

```
from concurrent.futures.process import ProcessPoolExecutor

class PoolBreaker(Exception):
    def __init__(self, num):
        super().__init__()
        print(f"PoolBreaker Constructor with num={num}")
        self.num = num


class NoPoolBreaker1(Exception):
    def __init__(self, num=-9):
        super().__init__()
        print(f"NoPoolBreaker1 Constructor with num={num}")
        self.num = num


class NoPoolBreaker2(Exception):
    def __init__(self, num):
        super().__init__(num)
        print(f"NoPoolBreaker2 Constructor with num={num}")
        self.num = num


class NoPoolBreaker3(Exception):
    def __init__(self, num):
        print(f"NoPoolBreaker3 Constructor with num={num}")
        self.num = num


def get_result(job):
    exc = job.exception()
    if type(exc) is PoolBreaker:
        print("PoolBreaker", exc.num)
    elif type(exc) is NoPoolBreaker1:
        print("NoPoolBreaker1", exc.num)
    elif type(exc) is NoPoolBreaker2:
        print("NoPoolBreaker2", exc.num)
    elif type(exc) is NoPoolBreaker3:
        print("NoPoolBreaker3", exc.num)
    else:
        print(f"Exception: {str(exc)}")


def work(x: int):
    if x == 0:
        raise PoolBreaker(x)
    elif x == 1:
        raise NoPoolBreaker1(x)
    elif x == 2:
        raise NoPoolBreaker2(x)
    elif x == 3:
        raise NoPoolBreaker3(x)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for num in range(0, 4):
        with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
            job = executor.submit(work, num)
        get_result(job)
```

and its output (python 3.7.3):

```
PoolBreaker Constructor with num=0
Exception: A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending.
NoPoolBreaker1 Constructor with num=1
NoPoolBreaker1 Constructor with num=-9
NoPoolBreaker1 1
NoPoolBreaker2 Constructor with num=2
NoPoolBreaker2 Constructor with num=2
NoPoolBreaker2 2
NoPoolBreaker3 Constructor with num=3
NoPoolBreaker3 Constructor with num=3
NoPoolBreaker3 3
```

As you can see the Constructor of the Exceptions is called two times, but let's go through the cases:

- PoolBreaker: The PoolBreaker Exception is successfully created. Afterwards, the lib inspects this Exception object and does not find any attribute. The constructor is called a second time, but no parameter is passed and so it fails. It is not done in the MWE, but if you would print the Stack trace you would see that it complains about `TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'num'`
- NoPoolBreaker1: It also does not find any attribute, but when the constructor is called with zero arguments, it does not fail because it has a default value (you see in the output that num=-9)
- NoPoolBreaker2: Since super() is called with the parameter, Exception has a `num` attribute. So the second call of the constructor receives the required `num` attribute with the correct value, so it works.
- NoPoolBreaker3: No super() is called and the NoPoolBreaker3 is inspected, and he finds the `num` attribute. So the second call of the constructor receives the required `num` attribute with the correct value, so it works.

The actual returned Exception is always the first one, the second one seems to be thrown away.

To transfer objects between processes they have to be pickled and copied, which is done by ProcessPoolExecutor. This *might* be the reason why the exception is created a second time.

Of course, this is not a solution of the problem, sadly I did not find anyone yet.

I meanwhile think, this could be a bug in the library because either:

- The second creation of the object is not intended, or
- The inspection of the attributes is faulty

Just a note: I currently have the problem that in a certain program NoPoolBreaker3 does not work any more and also causes the ‘terminated abruptly’ Exception. I have no clue why, but that probably means that the behaviour depends on more things than shown in the MWE.